# Given a series of varying widths and a point, find the width containing the point

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a world consisting of a series of rectangles with varying widths and offsets, but identical heights. I also have moving points, some of which are able to cross rectangle borders and others are not. Considering this fact, I am storing their positions as global coordinates and not relative to the rectangle (see red dots).

[image: world layout]

I need a fast way to lookup the rectangle a point is within given their X coordinate. For the image above, the two red dots will return the black and yellow rectangles respectively. The original solution I had buckles under a very large number of rectangles:

```java
    Rect getRectFor(float x) {
        float totalSum = 0.0f;

        // For each rect (in order)
        for (Rect rect : rects) {
            // Add the rect's width
            totalSum += rect.getWidth();

            // If the end of the rect is beyond us, return
            if (totalSum >= x) {
                return rect;
            }
        }

        // We are beyond the end of all rects
        return null;
    }
```

Are there any methods or data structures that would perform better in this scenario and allow me to perform thousands of lookups per second?

Comment: You can try to implement this with a `TreeMap`, where key is the X coordinate of where a rectangle starts, and value is the rectangle itself. Since `TreeMap` implements a red-black tree and has O(log n) complexity for retrieval operations, it will fit your needs. To find a rectangle you have to find the closest rectangle to the left of the dot.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, finding the closest rectangle to the left of the dot just reintroduces this same problem. I don't have a way to look that up without looping through each map as each is varying width.

Comment: You do not have to loop through all the values, it's a red-black tree structure. Use `TreeMap`'s `floorKey()` method to find the greatest key less than the given value in O(log n) time.

Comment: Is the range of `x` relatively small? Are the rectangles relatively stable? Are coordinates all integers? If so, create an array of dimension `x-max`, then 'render' the rectangles by populating the array with the id of the rectangle that falls within a range. Then you can directly index the array with the query `x` coordinate to get the id of the rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way I can think of is to create an array:

```
E[0] = 0
E[i] = x-coordinate indicating where the i-th ends.
```

In your example, it would be `E = {0, 100, 150, 225, 350, 375, ...}`.

To find the position of any dot, you can just perform a binary search in this array, giving you O(lg(n)) time per query.

---

Just to help, added a little piece of code:

```
int bs(int[] m, int l, int r, int dot){
    int i = (l + r) / 2;
    if(m[i - 1] < dot && dot < m[i]) return i;
    if(m[i - 1] == dot) return max(1, i - 1);
    if(m[i] == dot) return i;

    if(dot < m[i]) return bs(m, l, i, dot);
    else return bs(m, i + 1, r, dot);        
}
```

The arguments of `bs` are:

- `m`: your array.
- `l`: you should always use 1.
- `r`: you should always use `n - 1`, where `n` is the length of `m`.
- `dot`: the x-coordinate of your dot.

> Example: if you want to find the position of your second dot (in position x = 230), you should call
>
> `bs(E, 1, E.length - 1, 230)`
>
> and it would return 4.

If you try to run this method with a x-coordinate that is outsite the bounds of the array (for example, is the last rectangle ends in position x = 100 and you search a dot in x = 101), strange things may happen.